# How to display laravel eloquent data with jquery "Ajax" tooltip?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm a beginner in laravel. I have a index.blade.php file that data is in table form:

```html
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Available Date</td>
                <td colspan = 2>Actions</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="myTable">
            @foreach($event_detail['participants'] as $participant)
            <tr>
                <td class="can_filter">{{ $participant['id'] }}</td>
                <td class="can_filter" onmouseover="tooltip(this);">{{ $participant['name'] }}</td>
                <td class="can_filter">{{ $participant['date'] }}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{ route('participants.edit', $participant['id']) }}" class="btn btn-primary">
                        Edit</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form action="{{ route('participants.destroy', $participant['id']) }}" method="post">
                        @csrf
                        @method('DELETE')
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">
                            Delete</button>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

and I want to show some eloquent data(participant name, date which is in mysql DB. and it's connected already.) with this "tooltip(this);" JS function:

```
$("tr").tooltip({
            track: true,
               $.ajax({
                    url:  
                    type:'post',
                    data:
                    success: function(){
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

but I have no idea which attribute this tooltip function needs. any ideas?

Comment: Why not render the tooltip when the page load instead of doing another ajax call?

Comment: oh I got kind of a request from client(customer). I got to use ajax ;a;

Comment: When a client make a request, it is up to you what kind of solution will you provide unless they specify it should be ajax. Imagine playing your mouse all over the `tr` and there are multiple ajax spamming your server. Just a tip :)

Comment: Thx for your reply : ) yeah, it should be ajax.. I want to display [ `$participant->date`(supposed there's "participant" table and "date" column in DB) ] on tooltip using ajax. And also you're right.. hmm.. then  `onclick` might be better..

Answer (score 1):

I am going to give you the basic solution for this. Rest you will customize accordingly.
First you can add a default `title` attribute inside the HTML tag where you want to show the tooltip.

```
<td class="can_filter" id="tooltip_td" title="Any default tooltip title">{{ $participant['name'] }}</td>
```

Then in the jquery you can use the `title` attribute to add the tooltip title

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#tooltip_td').attr('title', "{{ $laravelTooltip }}");
    });
</script>
```

You can also do this without adding the default tooltip title. This is the basic solution and I hope you will get the basic understanding and can customize it at your own.

Comment: Thanks! But, I know how to use tooltip, but the thing is I got to use "Ajax". I want to display [ `$participant->date`(supposed there's "participant" table and "date" column in DB) ] on tooltip using ajax!

Comment: I have given you the basic info. You can use jQuery under ajax function

Comment: Like `$.ajax({
                    url:  
                    type:'post',
                    data:
                    success: function(data){
                      $('#tooltip_td').attr('title', data);   }
                });`